# PHP get url with variable value chosen

Tags: php, forms, post, dynamic, get

I'm trying to create a dynamic link with an option value but it doesn't work. Can someone help me find the error?

Here's my code:

```
<select id="ID1"name="provincia">
 <option value=""selected="selected">Seleziona dal menuù a tendina</option> 
 <option value="agrigento">Agrigento    </option> 
 <option value="alessandria">Alessandria    </option> 
 <option value="ancona">Ancona  </option> 
 <option value="aosta">Aosta    </option> 
 <option value="aquila">L'Aquila    </option> 
</select>

<a href="https://domainname.com/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=76&sld=<?php echo $_GET["provincia"]; ?>&systpl=e24&language=Italian"> Clicca Qui </a>
```

Comment: You don't need php for this... Link should be generated on same page, right?

Comment: This sounds like a Javascript thing...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you actually need javascript for this, otherwise you will need to send form via get (or post) method, refresh page (or use ajax) to update link... This is easier way, imho:

```
<select id="ID1"name="provincia" onchange="get_url(this.value);">
 <option value=""selected="selected">Seleziona dal menuù a tendina</option> 
 <option value="agrigento">Agrigento    </option> 
 <option value="alessandria">Alessandria    </option> 
 <option value="ancona">Ancona  </option> 
 <option value="aosta">Aosta    </option> 
 <option value="aquila">L'Aquila    </option> 
</select>

<a id="link" href="https://domainname.com/clients/cart.php?a=add&pid=76&sld=VAR&systpl=e24&language=Italian"> Clicca Qui </a>
```

JS:

```
function get_url(val) {
    link=document.getElementById('link');

link.href=link.href.replace(/sld=\w+/,'sld='+val);
    console.log(link.href);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/emjj473g/1/

(F12, open console, to see link updated, and/or click to link to see it really works...)

Explanation, if needed, you can call get_url() function with `onchange` event handler, and pass selected value to it, then replace desired part of `href` attribute of `a element`/link. Of course, you can make additional conditions to check value (e.g. user must select valid value to update link).

Comment: Inside <script> tags, before closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP something like this

```
<?php
$locations = ['Arizona', 'Siberia', 'Antarctica'];
if (isSet($_GET['selection'])) {
   $q = urlEncode($locations[$_GET['selection']]);
   header('Location: http://www.google.com/search?q=' . $q); }
?>
<form method="get" action="?">
   <p>
      <select id="selection" name="selection">
         <option value="0">Arizona</option>
         <option value="1">Siberia</option>
         <option value="2">Antarctica</option>
      </select>
   </p>
   <p><input type="submit"/></p>
</form>
```